# Including CoffeeScript file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have taken a look at coffeeScript and really want to try it out in my rails app. i know that from rails 3.1 that coffeeScript is now included within rails. but i am having some issues getting it to work.

I have a file called `lens.js` that i have renamed `lens.js.coffee`, and then converted all my js into coffee. From the screen casts i have seen and the blogs i have read that seemed to be all i needed. but its not picking up the file somehow.

```
GET http://www.cairo.dev/javascripts/lens.js 404 (Not Found)
```

is what the console is dropping. i am including it like this with all my other js files.

```
= javascript_include_tag 'lens', 'jquery-ui.min', 'rails', 'application', 'popup', 'jquery.zclip', 'underscore-min'
```

Note: that link is HAML

Which should work since it compiles it from coffeeScript into js. then i wondered if it wasn't installed so i added `gem 'coffee-script'` to my gemfile and i bundled still nothing.

am i doing something stupid. or what am i missing?

Comment: did you restart the server after bundling?

Comment: is `lens.js.coffee` in the `app/assets/javascripts` directory?

Comment: this app was built before the asset pipeline was set for there. so i am busy upgrading it now. hopefully this will solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to add `gem 'coffee-script'` in your gemfile but:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end
```

If that doesn't work, you can try removing your `lens` from the `javascript_include_tag` and make sure you have this line in your `application.js`:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: i just tried that and still no dice.. is there nothing like a coffeescript_include_tag ? haha

Comment: Are you sure you tried the second option? Actually, by using it you can remove all the libraries from the javascript_include_tag and just leave: javascript_include_tag :application

Comment: Nop : ) Have you got a `config.assets.enabled = true` in your **config/application.rb**? Did you run another `bundle install` after changing the Gemfile?

Comment: when i added `config.assets.endabled = true` it dropped all my assets.  and yeah i ran bundle install. and restarted the app since i am using pow.

Comment: What do you mean? You're not supposed to have static assets in development anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Try `rake assets:clean`. It seems that sometimes Rails reads the precompiled assets in development environment.

**SOURCE**
[Rails 3.1 not detecting Coffeescript and Javascript changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025370/rails-3-1-not-detecting-coffeescript-and-javascript-changes)